# Blazor new WebAssembly App doesnt show the install app option

Tags: blazor, webassembly

When I create a vanilla blazor webassembly app clicking ASP.Net Server Hosted and also the PWA option in the last week (over 5 test projects) and run the code as the Client as the startup project the INSTALL WASM button doesnt show?

The last month I have created a few Test projects and the install APP button appears but now I cannot get it to show. I have cleared all chrome cache and cleaned the blazor solution but for some reason the button to install doesnt show. I have double checked on the Microsoft website that all my settings are correct at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

but still the install buttons doesnt show in the browser. I am using VS for MAC and then just used my Windows server using VS for MS and still the same, the default create new blazor webassembly app doesnt show the INSTALL app.

Is it something to do with the latest version of VS that has a bug ?

Comment: The startup project for the "Hosted" Blazor Web Assembly template solution is the Server project, not the Client project.

Comment: This related question might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58985103/progressive-web-app-not-showing-install-button-in-browser-bar

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, unfortunalely it is none of these. I do have the start up project set to client and I have zero errors in my dev tools console. Its wierd as I had to workingh back in December creating new projects but this week the install option button is not showing.

Comment: If you are using the hosted template, leave the startup project to server. Why would you set the startup project to client? Your app might just break because there is no server running.

Comment: I have tried to create a Blazor WASM with the PWA selected without ASP.NET Core Hosted and it still doesn't show the install button. I am using VS 2022 for MAC OS and also VS 2022 on Microsoft Windows. Not sure what I have done as it was all working back in December but now creating any new project with the PWA option selected it doesn't show the install button on 2 separate dev machines

Comment: I have found a strange way to make it work. If I open the chrome dev tools and go to lighthouse and generate a report, it will then show the install button for that url and thereafter will always show the install button. Maybe its something to do with chrome blocking the manifest or something untill i open lighthouse

Comment: Why there is no install button for the url when using Edge?

Answer (score 0):

Start a debug session.
Open a new browser instance and point it to the same URL that your debug session is in.
The button should be visible.