# Blazor PWA in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, blazor, progressive-web-apps, visual-studio-2022

in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.1.5 I have created a Blazor PWA project with .NET 5 and when I launch the template in debug or release mode it cannot be installed to Windows.

With Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.13 it is working fine.

Is there a way to make it work in Visual Studio 2022 or is this a bug?

Comment: You need to Publish (that's more than just a Release).  I'm surprised it worked with VS2019.

Comment: I just created PWA .NET 5 from template in VS2022 and installed it from localhost in Chrome. However, I could not install in Edge.  When you have problems with a PWA, check the browser dev tools Application tab and click on manifest to find the problem. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63524621/943435